# Why DOES this code work and give correct results?

Tags: c, fopen, fread

I have two files, one is called N.bin and the other is called R.bin. After couple of months of using it, I just noticed that I have a mistake there. However, I thought the system would crash because of it. But first it didn't and second it gives the correct result. Here is the code:

Please see Line 19 how I mistakenly streamed in from Nfile and not Rfile .

// Read file N

```
1       long world_features_lSize;
2       FILE* NFile;
3       double* N;
4       NFile=fopen("N.bin","r+b");
5   
6       fseek (NFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
7       lSize = ftell (NFile);
8       fseek (NFile , 0 , SEEK_SET);
9       N = (double*) malloc (sizeof(double)*lSize);
10      result = fread (N,1,lSize,NFile);
11      fclose(NFile);
    ////////////////// Read R

12      FILE* RFile;
13      double* R;
14      RFile=fopen("R.bin","r+b");

15      fseek (RFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
16      lSize = ftell (RFile);
17      fseek (RFile , 0 , SEEK_SET);
18      R = (double*) malloc (sizeof(double)*lSize);
19      result = fread (R,1,lSize,NFile);
20      fclose(RFile);
```

Kindly advice me why does this code work !!

Comment: `RFile` ended up being stored the same place as `NFile` for whatever reason (or the same file descriptor or whatever is used).

Comment: Probably N and R share the same Filedescriptor since you closed NFile freeing it's descriptor and when opening RFile the os just gave you the same descriptor but for a different file. I'm assuming you are on a *NIX platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably down to the way the C run time libraries handle memory allocation. `fopen` mallocs a buffer since it returns a `FILE *` object. `fclose` frees the buffer. The subsequent `fopen` will malloc a buffer the same size as before and it just happened to return the same memory the previous `free` released. If you compare the pointer values of R and N they will be the same.

Note that if you had done any memory allocation \ freeing between lines 11 and 14, then the system would have crashed. Also, depending on how the debugger works and the run time, the `free` function can sometimes be made to not reuse the freed memory.

To prevent this sort of bug in the future, always do this:

```
fclose (handle);
handle = 0; // so you get a null pointer error if you accidentally use it again
```

Comment: Many thanks Skizz. And you 100% correct, R and N have same pointer :D. Now i get it.